# Is there a way to get YT url or video ID from playlist with pafy?

Tags: python, pafy

I am trying to make a program that takes YT playlist and play all it's content.

I've installed all components needed for pafy to run with python3. Everything I've tried works as it's expected, except the bellow part of the code.

```
plurl = "https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL634F2B56B8C346A2"
playlist = pafy.get_playlist(plurl)
url = playlist['items'][21]['pafy'].getbest().url
video = pafy.new(url)
```

When `pafy.new()` is called, gives an error because of too long url:

```
Need 11 character video id or the URL of the video. Got https://r2---sn-bavc5aoxu-nv4l.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?ms=au%2Crdu&sparams=clen%2Cdur%2Cei%2Cgir%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpl%2Cratebypass%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cexpire&mv=m&mt=1554899146&requiressl=yes&ip=37.157.173.53&pl=19&id=o-AGQZkyoEvykUGae7O4v_Ycmuj4jJBYdgafcfLBQ5S4Dd&mn=sn-bavc5aoxu-nv4l%2Csn-nv47lnsr&mm=31%2C29&source=youtube&lmt=1387649403290510&ei=POGtXJzdIo_ugAeEiL_wAQ&c=WEB&key=yt6&mime=video%2Fmp4&gir=yes&itag=18&clen=5461830&fvip=2&expire=1554920860&ratebypass=yes&dur=206.100&initcwndbps=1573750&ipbits=0&signature=AAA8B36CD3B402F587F874956595ACB928806C4F.D36C0A79E7F1727DB872425E696DBFC550AA7DF6
```

Is there a way I can get normal url or video ID ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The videoid is also available in the url object. You can use

```
dir(<object>)
```

to see what properties are available.

```
id = playlist['items'][2]['pafy'].videoid
video = pafy.new('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v='+id)
```

use *try and catch* before using *pafy.new* , as some of the videos might not be available in the region.